# I want to convert html page into pdf file

Tags: itext

I want to convert an HTML page into a PDF document, but my program shows the error `The number of columns in pdfptable constructor must be greater than zero`

This is my code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ulcact.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
tb1.RenderControl(hw);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
htmlparser.Parse(sr);//error should be gone
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

What could cause this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: your stringwriter is empty. try adding some html content into it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons for this error, but when i faced this problem it was due to incorrect or dirty HTML.

First of all please check if your StringWriter is Empty or not. Then Debug the code to see what you get in it before the htmlparser.Parse(sr); line.

Secondly if while debugging you see that the HTML is dirty, then you have to clean the HTML. there is a library that does it and its called HTMLTidy. Search for it on stackoverflow and you will find many posts on how to use it. Use HTMLTidy to clean your HTML and then give the htmlparser.Parse method the clean HTML and it should work.